# Need information on query parameters for Google Books e.g. difference between &dq and &q, &f, &redir_esc, etc

Tags: html, parameters, httpwebrequest

In books with "Snippet view" available (where you can view snippets of text in a page) to link to highlighted text represented by `<search_string>`, I can any one of the following forms of the URL:

```
http://books.google.com/books?id=<book_id>&q=<search_string>&dq=<search_string>
http://books.google.com/books?id=<book_id>&q=<search_string>
http://books.google.com/books?id=<book_id>&dq=<search_string>
```

In books with "Preview" available (where you can view full pages) links to highlighted text add `&pg=<page_number>` after `&id=<book_id>` to a URL in one of the above forms. I've discovered that that such a URL always works when it has both `&dq` and `&q` but queries with only `&dq` or only `&q` don't work with some books.

I've also noticed that `&f=false` tends to be automatically appended to the query when you click on the link.

What do these parameters `&q`, `&dq`, `&f` and `&redir_esc=y#v=onepage` mean? Where I can find this information and information on how to use query parameters in general for Google Books? I've searched but can't find anything with this specific information.

Note: Different books use different page number formats. In my experience, `<page number>` in the URL for a book with "Preview" available can be one of the following forms:

- `PAx` where x is the actual page number in the book. x is also sometimes a number that is not the actual page number e.g. x is a four digit number that exceeds the number of pages in the book.
- `PTx` where x may not be actual page number in the printed book, which may not be shown on the page in the Google Books viewer.
- `PRx` where x is the number of a page preceding the first chapter e.g. page iii in the book is linked to with `&pg=PR3`
- `SLz-PAx` where the pages of the book are of the form `<section><page>` with z as the index number of the section in the book and x the page number in that section e.g. page C17 is is linked to with `&pg=SL3-PA17`

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that `&dq` allows highlighting in books where there is "Preview" available and `&pg=PTx` is in the URL, where x is the number of the page on Google Books but not the page number on the page in the printed book. Also, if you use a url without `&redir_esc=y#v=onepage` for a book with "Preview" available, usually `&dq` shows the highlighted text in full page view whereas `&q` shows the snippet view (so you have to click on the snippet to see the full page).

Answer (score 0):

`&q` is your main query.
`&dq` is ISSN/LCCN/OCLCnum query, it is the standard name of the book.
`&f`  is the bool for sidebar. false value shows the sidebar, true value hides it. Basically setting it to true will tell the API to not to bother to add the sidebar HTML in the HTML coding.
`&redir_esc` accepts two values, y or n, though I've seen it with empty values in some urls. I'm not sure about its purpose.
`#v=onepage` is the parameter that sets view of the Book in the browser. onepage sets the view to Single Page View. `snippet` sets it to Snippet View.

Comment: Thx, is this documented anywhere? I've seen use of `&dq` with ISBN queries i.e. `&dq=isbn:<isbn number>`. In this case, you must still have the `&id` parameter in the url and url still works using just the `&id` without the `&dq`. In my question I was talking about use of `&dq` for highlighting text in a book. See my answer below.